# Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am learning Spring MVC and Spring Security without Spring Boot
Here is the error that I am getting, related to Spring Security. When I am setting DaoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(), it seems the bean for jpaUserDetailsManager is not yet instantiated or not instantiated at all

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'jpaDaoAuthenticationProvider' defined in io.angel.config.SecurityConfig: A UserDetailsService must be set
```

SecurityConfig.java is the class where I define all security related config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JpaUserDetailsManager jpaUserDetailsManager;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);


    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(4);
    }


    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider jpaDaoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(jpaUserDetailsManager);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(
            HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .authenticationProvider(jpaDaoAuthenticationProvider())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .formLogin(customizer ->
                        customizer
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .successHandler(
                                        (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) -> {
                                            LOGGER.info(
                                                    ((User) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername() + " authenticated!"
                                            );
                                        }
                                )
                                .failureHandler(
                                        (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) -> {
                                            LOGGER.info(
                                                    "Authentication failed! " + exception.getLocalizedMessage()
                                            );
                                        }
                                )
                                .permitAll())
                .logout(customizer ->
                        customizer.logoutSuccessUrl("/home"))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authorize -> authorize
                                .requestMatchers("/profile")
                                .authenticated()
                                .anyRequest()
                                .permitAll())

                .build();
    }
}


    @Service
    public class JpaUserDetailsManager implements UserDetailsManager {
    
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;
        @Override
        public void createUser(UserDetails user) {
            userRepository.save((User)user);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void updateUser(UserDetails user) {
            userRepository.save((User) user);
        }
    
        @Transactional
        @Override
        public void deleteUser(String username) {
            User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found for username -> " + username));
            userRepository.delete(user);
        }
    
        @Transactional
        @Override
        public void changePassword(String oldPassword, String newPassword) {
            User user = userRepository
                    .findByPassword(oldPassword)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid password!"));
            user.setPassword(newPassword);
            userRepository.save(user);
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean userExists(String username) {
            return userRepository
                    .findByUsername(username)
                    .isPresent();
        }
    
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            return userRepository
                    .findByUsername(username)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username = " + username));
        }
    }
```

I have tried defining JpaUserDetailsManager as a Java bean instead of using annotation `@Service`, but didn't really help and shouldn't make a difference. I have experience coding in Spring Boot, and haven't really noticed this issue so far, but I can't start the app using only Spring MVC and Security.

Comment: read the docs, the error is super clear you have to implement the `UserDetailsService` interface that is used by form login to lookup the user when you are logging in. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/user-details-service.html

Comment: you can remove the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and you can remove the `UserDetailsManager` implementation, all you need is to implement `UserDetailsService` and everything else will be automatically taken care of by the framework. As said before, read the docs!

Comment: I have JpaUserDetailsManager implemented,which extends UserDetailsService

Comment: @Toerktumlare I am not using Spring Boot, if I remove those two components the app won't work.

Comment: `won’t work` is an extremly bad way of describing an error. Then you are doing things wrong.

Comment: @AngelGruevski Check this line `daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(jpaUserDetailsManager);`. I would say that `jpaUserDetailsManager` is `null`. It would be easier to answer your question if you had add the stacktrace.

Comment: @dur you are correct. jpaUserDetailsManager was null. Instead of using field injection I refactored the code to use constructor injection and the issue was solved,not sure why but it works.

However now I am having an issue with .requestMatchers() method. If I use this method in the SecurityFilterChain DSL, the following exception occurs:

`Circular reference involving containing bean 'securityConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance.`

Comment: @AngelGruevski So your question is solved. Write a follow-up question with your new problem. Add new code, full error message and stack trace to this new question.

Comment: @dur yes, thank you very much for indicating about the null value!